# Coding Bot, using Proxy over http or https

Tags: python, http, https, proxy, bots

i want to program a bot with proxies. The bot should buy things. For this it is important that he types in some user accounts and passwords. My problem here is that I don't know if it is problematic to use http-proxies. I red something about that http communication is not safe and the messages are not encoded. So everyone can see my username and my password. Am I right?
Does anyone have some tips or suggestions?

Comment: If the target server uses HTTPS and the proxy allows the HTTP CONNECT method, then the proxy can't see the password, as it's end-to-end HTTPS protected. Other forms of proxy connect methods may allow the proxy to see the password. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_method.

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much! @deceze